# Interchanging between different scipy ode solvers

Tags: python, scipy

I have a made a solver which can interchange between `scipy.integrate.ode` and `scipy.integrate.odeint`. Here is the code.

```
def f(y,s,C,u,v):
    y0 = y[0] # u
    y1 = y[1] # u'
    y2 = y[2] # v
    y3 = y[3] # v'
    dy = np.zeros_like(y)
    dy[0] = y1
    dy[2] = y3

    C = C.subs({u:y0,v:y2})
    dy[1] = -C[0,0][0]*dy[0]**2\
            -2*C[0,0][1]*dy[0]*dy[2]\
            -C[0,1][1]*dy[2]**2
    dy[3] = -C[1,0][0]*dy[0]**2\
            -2*C[1,0][1]*dy[0]*dy[2]\
            -C[1,1][1]*dy[2]**2
    return dy

def solve(C,u0,s0,s1,ds,solver=None):
    from sympy.abc import u,v
    if solver == None: # use lsoda from scipy.integrate.odeint
        s = np.arange(s0,s1+ds,ds)
        print 'Running solver ...'
        return sc.odeint(f,u0,s,args=(C,u,v))
    else: # use any other solver from scipy.integrate.ode
        r = sc.ode(f).set_integrator(solver) # vode,zvode,lsoda,dopri5,dop853
        r.set_f_params(C,u,v)
        r.set_initial_value(u0)
        #t = []
        y = []
        print 'Running solver ...'
        while r.successful() and r.t <= s1:
            r.integrate(r.t + ds)
            y.append(r.y)#; t.append(r.t)
        return np.array(y)
```

The problem I experience is as following. If I decide to use the solver from `scipy.integrate.odeint` then the parameters of `f` have to be specified in the order as they are in the code. However, if I decide to use the solvers from `scipy.integrate.ode` I have to change the order of the parameters of the function `f(y,s,C,u,v)` to  `f(s,y,C,u,v)`, otherwise I get the error

```
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

If I do this, then `scipy.integrate.odeint` generates the same error for `f` defined as `f(s,y,C,u,v)`. How can I operate with a unified `f` regardless of the order of the parameters ?

**Edit :**

To sum the problem up :

`scipy.integrate.ode` solvers work if the function f is defined as `f(s,y,C,u,v)`, and `scipy.integrate.odeint` solver works if the function f is defined as `f(y,s,C,u,v)`. Why is this occurring, and how I can I fix this?

**Edit :**

Scipy -- version 0.16.0

Comment: If I interchange the s and y parameters, the solver tries to access a float as if it were a list. This is causing the error message above.

Comment: But why do you need the ```odeint``` in general? The ```odeint``` uses ```lsoda``` solver which is avaliable in ```ode``` as well.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Originally I was using odeint, but then I wanted to add the possibility to use other solvers as well (besides Lsoda). The code shown in this example is only a fraction of the whole code. I guess I was being lazy by not wanting to change the code. But I also thought that the question seemed relevant, since it was odd that these two solvers had different variable maps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is this occurring, and how I can I fix this?

It is occurring because of an unfortunate API design decision made years ago.  `odeint` and the `ode` class require different signatures for the system to be solved.

You can fix it by adding a wrapper that changes the order of the first two arguments when you use, say, the `ode` class.  For example, you could change this:

```
    r = sc.ode(f).set_integrator(solver)
```

to

```
    r = sc.ode(lambda t, x, *args: f(x, t, *args)).set_integrator(solver)
```

---

*Update*:  In SciPy 1.1.0, the argument `tfirst` was added to [`scipy.integrate.odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html).  The default, `tfirst=False`, maintains the old behavior.  With `tfirst=True`, `odeint` expects the *first* argument of 
`func` to be `t` (i.e. the independent variable).  By using `tfirst=True`, the same `func` can be used with `ode`, `odeint` and the newer `solver_ivp`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm. This way, I can still use the same function f without having to either physically changing the order of the parameters, or creating a new function.