# Solving ODE with scipy.integrate.ode and scipy.integrate.odeint give different results

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy, ode

I am trying to solve a simple ODE with both odeint and ode methods of SciPy. The example I am using is the disease spread (I will later try to solve my more complex ODEs). The function should look like this:

[image]

My odeint code gives results that are acceptable.

```
from scipy import *
import scipy.integrate as integ
from pylab import * 

def dydt(y,t):
    K=0.00003
    L=250000
    return K*y*(L-y)

t=linspace(0,12,61)
y=integ.odeint(dydt, 250, t)
plot(t,y)
show()
```

But when I try to do the same with ode method I get quite different (and incorrect results and the plot apparently shows that). What I am doing incorrectly?

```
from scipy.integrate import ode
from pylab import * 
from numpy import *

y0, t0 = 250, 0

def dydt(y,t):
    K=0.00003
    L=250000
    return K*y*(L-y)

r = ode(dydt).set_integrator('vode', method='bdf')
r.set_initial_value(y0, t0)

t1 = 10.0
dt = 0.1

sol = []

while r.successful() and r.t < t1:
    r.integrate(r.t + dt)
    sol.append([r.t, r.y])

sol = array(sol)
plot(sol[:,0],sol[:,1])
show()
```

Note that r.y contains real values and that's why I could draw just the real part.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522706/interchanging-between-different-scipy-ode-solvers/33523944#33523944

Comment: Your equation is real.  You could use "vode" instead of "zvode".

Comment: Waren, thanks. I changed that (I was using it for a complex one, it was left there). By the way, does the question have similar problem to mine?

Comment: Oh, got it. The order of arguments of the function should be changed! Thank you. I guess you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Or you might self-close the question as a duplicate.  I'm sure this question--in various guises--has been asked many times.

Comment: I added my vote for close. I could not close it outright.

Comment: Ok, I hit it with the dup hammer. 