# solving stiff ODE using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, ode, numerical-integration

I am sorry for this is a really basic question. I am trying to solve stiff ODE with the help of set.integrator('vode',method='bdf'). However I am not able to exactly understand the syntax and errors keeps showing up. This is the first time I am dealing with this any help in this would be great.
Here's the code I have used:

```
def f(y,t):
    f0 = y[0]*(onr/(y[0]**3) + (H**2)*(y[2]**2)/(2.0*rho_c) + (v0*np.exp(-l*y[1]*k))/(rho_c))**(1.0/2.0)
    f1 =  y[2]
    f2 =  -3*y[2]*(H**2)*(onr/(y[0]**3) + (H**2)*(y[2]**2)/(2.0*rho_c) + (v0*np.exp(-l*y[1]*k))/(rho_c))**0.5 + (l*k*v0*np.exp(-l*y[1]*k))/(H**2)
    return [f0,f1,f2]

#y[0] = 1.0
#y[1] = 1.0
#y[3] = c
y0 = [1.0,1.0,c]
t0 = 1.0
t1 = 0.0
t = np.linspace(start=1.0,stop=0.0,num=100001)

solver = ode(f).set_integrator('vode',method='bdf')
solver.set_initial_value(y0,t0)

y,t = [],[]

while solver.t>t1:
    solver.integrate(t1,step=True)
    y.append(solver.y)
    t.append(solver.t)
y = np.array(y)
t = np.array(t)


X = solver[:,0]
Y = solver[:,1]
Z = solver[:,2]
```

I am not sure what is wrong here. When I run this `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`keeps showing up.

Comment: For the `ode` class, the signature of the function that defines the system of differential equations must be `f(t,y)`, not `f(y,t)`.  I'd make this an answer, but I'm sure it is a duplicate several times over.

Comment: See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522706/interchanging-between-different-scipy-ode-solvers

Comment: In the last line, are you sure you want do slice `solver` or the just computed `y`? Most likely, `y` will be constant the last value, you need to copy `solver.y` to avoid only copying the reference.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thanks that helped.

Comment: @LutzL yeah it is taking only the last value. What should I do if I want to take the entire array and to plot y[0],y[1],y[2] against some other values?

Comment: You need to create a copy, `solver.y.copy()`. Then `X=y[:,0]` etc.